# Lookup Table Input Variable Issue

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am using a lookup table to successfully apply different UA-ID codes to the same universal analytics tag. However, for one particular UA-ID, I need to send data from all pages with the exception of data from a particular sub domain.  i.e. something like this:

input variable : *.example.com except abc.example.com

Not sure how to implement this logic for the input variable of a lookup table.

Also, if I specify "example.com" as an input variable, does it capture all subdomains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit in Jan 2018 for latest info.

For lookup tables you need to know 2 things:

1. Lookup table input variables do a hard match.  I.e. its simply an 'equals' only, no 'contains' or 'starts with' or regex etc.
2. Lookup tables are sequential, the matching starts from the top and stops as soon as a match is found.  Much like an if then elseif (without an 'else' available at the end!)
3. You can apply a default value if none of the rows in the table match.

There are now Regex Tables available as well which will enable you to do partial matches on values and return a value based on that.  For full and comprehensive details, read the article by [Simo](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/the-regex-table-variable-in-google-tag-manager/)

In your case you have 3 options:

1. Use a Regex Table Lookup
2. list each and every hostname (inc subdomain) you want to match and apply the correct UA number to each.  You should end up with as many lines as you do sub-domains.
3. Create a new custom javascript variable which inspects the current host (inc subdomain) and returns whether its 'abc.example.com' or '.example.com' (indicating any other sub domain) and then you'll just need a couple of lines in your lookup table.

Comment: There is an 'else' available at the end , because it's possible to set a default value ;)